# pySerial read_until() reads only the first byte

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

So I'm receiving data from a serial port using pySerial. I've a very simple code that reads the first byte, check if it's the start byte ( `0x02` in my case) and then read until it finds the end byte ( `0x03` in my case).

Config the serial communciation

```
port = 'COM3'
baud = 38400

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=0)
if ser.isOpen():
    ser.close()
    ser.open()

ser.reset_input_buffer()
ser.reset_output_buffer()
```

The main loop is inside a `while True` staement as below.

```
while True:
    data = ""
    data_raw = ser.read(1)
    if data_raw == b'\x02':
        data_raw = ser.read_until(b'\x03')
        print(str(data_raw))
        ser.reset_input_buffer()
        ser.reset_output_buffer()
        time.sleep(.5)
```

The issue is that, for some reason, the `read_until()` actually reads only the first bye while the data I'm receiving from the serial port are actually `b'\x02\xff\x9c\x81E1\x03\'`

After reading correctly the `\x02` the `read_until()` statement just read only the next `\xff` and I can't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bug never fixed by the `pySerial` module itself https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/181

Using `timeout=None` in `serial.Serial()` resolved the issue